# Can I detect browser's TLS Version via Code?

Tags: javascript, security, user-agent, tls1.2, browser-detection

I want to show some warning message on browsers which has the TLS version 1.0 or older. 
How will I determine the TLS Version of Browser via Code ?
I can have access to User Agent String. I don't think it's mentioned there.

[Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Web_browsers) to TLS Version for all the major browsers. Please refer the Table.

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: How about diabling it server side? e.g. apache: https://serverfault.com/questions/848177/how-can-i-disable-tls-1-0-and-1-1-in-apache

Comment: I can't do it that way, Other services on Server must go on.
Apart from that, I just need to show a warning msz if the TLS version is outdated. I need not to shut down service. (I'll reframe the question) Thanks for the idea anyway @RolandStarke

Answer (score 1):

The TLS parameters are negotiated during the TLS handshake (when you initially connect to the site) and depend on the browser and server capabilities.

I don't believe browsers offer ways to programmatically query this information. Nor do I think your site should be warning users about the TLS connection. This is really the job of the browser. Why should users trust your site to correctly display that information?

All modern browsers allow users to inspect the TLS parameters of the connection. Chrome for example shows this info in the security tab under developers tools.

Your best option is to disable insecure TLS versions on the server.

Having said that, you could of course build code server side to expose this information or subscribe to something like https://www.howsmyssl.com/s/api.html which does this for you.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer :) Especially : Why should users trust your site to correctly display that information?

Comment: But anyway, users are restricted and trusting our site for their secure payments. I am doing it for 6 Major Browsers ( Chrome,Opera, FireFox, Safari, IE, and Edge). and below is how I do it : 
Currently I am fetching the browser version and comparing it to the minimum version having TLS 1.1, and allowing accordingly.

Comment: It's like these lock icons people put on websites to gain the trust of a user. The site itself should not be the source of trust for this. When a new attack against TLS is found, the browser vendors will react and update their browsers (and users should make sure their browsers are up-to-date). There's absolutely no guarantee sites will update their code to reflect the latest status in TLS security. I'm not saying warning a user about this is wrong, but users should be trained to know the indicators that the browser has about their connection security instead of trusting any random website.

Comment: Browser will anyway do it's work !!! It will be an additional warning. Something is better than nothing. :)

Comment: Yes, but I'm still not convinced. It's much easier to check the agent-string and warn the user they're using and old browser and you recommend they upgrade.

Comment: Yeah, that's easy for 5 browsers, but what about new browsers in market or the browsers I am have not included in my test cases ?
A general solution will be to check the TLS Version for all browsers. @MvdD